# I think I was wrong: The supremum of a set whose elements squared less than a positive real number is square root of this number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I think I was wrong... Can you find it out and teach me how to prove (the title)?

If $c>0$ a real number. Define $E=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^2<c\}$. $E$ is nonempty because $0\in E$ (positivity axiom). Call $x_0=\sup E$. $E$ is also bound from above because $(c+1)^2>c>x^2 \Rightarrow c+1>|x|$. How to show $x_0^2=c$? The following is my reasoning.

Define a new set $U=\{y\in\mathbb R\mid y^2\ge c\}$, so all $y$ is an upper bound of $E$. $x_0\in U$ due to the completeness axiom. Therefore, $x_0^2\ge c$. We can exclude $x_0^2>c$ in the following way:

Suppose $x_0^2>c$. $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $x_0^2-2x_0\epsilon+\epsilon^2>c$. So $x_0>x_0-\epsilon>x, \forall x\in E$, which is impossible because $x_0=\sup E$.

Is this correct?

There is always a trick to deal with this kind of problem. If we want to show $x_0^2=c$, we can first show $x_0^2\ge c$, as I did (if I was correct), then show $x_0^2\le c$. But in this problem, it seems to me that it is difficult to show the other half. Is there anybody who can use this trick?

Comment: uh, I made a typo. Should be $(c+1)^2>c>x^2$.

Comment: $c$ is a positive number because $0\le x^2<c$. So is $c+1$. We can open the absolute value brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that for small $\varepsilon$, $\sqrt n - \varepsilon$ is a member of the set and that no element greater than $\sqrt n$ is in the set.  The second part should be easy.

For the first part, $(\sqrt n - \varepsilon)^2 = n +\varepsilon^2 -2\sqrt n \varepsilon = \sqrt n (\sqrt n + \frac{\varepsilon ^2}{\sqrt n}  - 2 \varepsilon)$

For ultimately small $\varepsilon$, the second factor will be less than the first, implying the membership in the set.  For any given $\varepsilon$, you can argue that there is an integer $k$ for which $1/k < \varepsilon$.  Replace $\varepsilon$ with 1/k and I think you'll see it immediately.

Comment: Your calculation in the 2nd graph is wrong. It should be $\sqrt n (\sqrt n +\epsilon^2/\sqrt n-2\epsilon)$. Other than that, I cannot figure out how $1/k<\epsilon$ leads to $\epsilon^2/\sqrt n-2\epsilon<\sqrt n$.

Comment: Because for very small numbers (such as 1/k for large k), the square is actually smaller than the original number.  Get a common denominator for $(1/k)^2/\sqrt{n} - 2(1/k)$ and see what happens.